# How does Sencha Touch prevent scrolling to the grey background on iphone?

Tags: sencha-touch, mobile-website

On perusing the Sencha Touch kitchen sink, I noticed that they have somehow disabled scrolling "the entire page/app", which happens if you grab the top of the page and drag down, such that the grey area/background behind is shown on the iPhone (hope you know what I mean). In every other framework I've seen, such as JQM and JQTouch, grey happens. So, how did they do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is set the overflow CSS property on the body to `hidden`.

```
<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden
    }
</style>
```

The reason Sencha Touch can do this is because they have their own custom scroller, whereas most other frameworks rely on the browsers native scrollable capabilities.

Comment: should changing sencha css to "overflow: scroll" in a sencha app cause it to behave like a normal scrollable page? It's what i'd line to do but it's not working...